is there any possiblity to send braodcast messages using Whatsapp Cloud API without third party?
is there any possibility to send broadcast messages using WhatsApp Cloud API without third party?
can you please share any alternative way to send broadcast messages and how to check the delivered and read status. thanks in advance.

to send broadcast message you first need to create a whatsapp template message and get it approved from whatsapp and later send it as a broadcast message to whatsapp contact using api refer to this official document
